# Как найти вызываемый скрипт?

Tags: javascript, php

Доброе утро/день/вечер.
Есть сайт на WordPress для для управляющих компаний с данными о ЛС, начислениях, оплате и т.д.
Поставили задачу исправить печатную форму, начал искать скрипт, рисующий эту самую форму.
Наткнулся на скрипт, который после нажатия кнопки "Печать" вызывает функцию, который рисует эту форму, но не могу понять где находится эта самая функция.
P.S. Сайт изначально написан не мной.

Comment: grep -r 'кусок кода формы' /

Comment: Это Windows 10, a не Linux

Comment: Поиск по файлам в пхпшторме

Comment: Если вдруг - это блокнот, а не шторм то у меня больше нет вариантов

Comment: Обычный Notepad++

Comment: @РашенБеар а вдруг там вообще ssh-терминал и в нем nano!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Открываете консоль разработчика Google Chrome, нажимаете

```
Ctrl+Shift+F
```

(или поиск по всем файлам страницы) и вводите интересующую Вас строку.

p.s. использую горячие клавиши:

```
Ctrl+Shift+J - открыть консоль
Ctrl+Shift+F - открыть поиск
Ctrl+Shift+M - переключиться в адаптивный режим
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло